# JPA Converter unnessecary call of "convertToDatabaseColumn" leads to ClassCastException

Tags: java, jpa, enums, eclipselink, java-ee-7

I have a `Converter` to convert the `String` stored in the DB to the corresponding `Enum` element:

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class DokumentTypConverter implements AttributeConverter<DokumentTypSchluessel, String> {

   @Override
   public String convertToDatabaseColumn(DokumentTypSchluessel attribute) {
      return attribute.getValue();
   }

   @Override
   public DokumentTypSchluessel convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
      return DokumentTypSchluessel.from(dbData);
   }
}
```

I have an Entity class which has a field of the Enum type:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REF_DOKUMENTTYPEN")
public class DokumentTyp {
   private DokumentTypSchluessel schluessel;
   // snip
}
```

Now when I try to retrieve an instance of that entity from the db

```
String query = "SELECT d FROM DokumentTyp d WHERE d.schluessel = " + VORBEREITUNG;
entityManager.createQuery(query, DokumentTyp.class).getSingleResult();
```

I get the following error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: An exception occurred while calling convertToDatabaseColumn on converter class de.drvbund.pub.model.convert.DokumentTypConverter with value VORBEREITUNG
        at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.ConverterClass.convertObjectValueToDataValue(ConverterClass.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.getFieldValue(AbstractDirectMapping.java:778)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.QueryKeyExpression.getFieldValue(QueryKeyExpression.java:420)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ConstantExpression.printSQL(ConstantExpression.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.ExpressionOperator.printDuo(ExpressionOperator.java:2241)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.printSQL(CompoundExpression.java:286)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.printSQL(RelationExpression.java:899)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionSQLPrinter.translateExpression(ExpressionSQLPrinter.java:325)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionSQLPrinter.printExpression(ExpressionSQLPrinter.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.printSQL(SQLSelectStatement.java:1755)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabasePlatform.printSQLSelectStatement(DatabasePlatform.java:3268)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform.printSQLSelectStatement(OraclePlatform.java:967)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.buildCall(SQLSelectStatement.java:843)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.buildCall(SQLSelectStatement.java:854)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.buildCallFromStatement(ClassDescriptor.java:815)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.setCallFromStatement(StatementQueryMechanism.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.prepareSelectAllRows(StatementQueryMechanism.java:315)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareSelectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:1723)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepareSelectAllRows(ReadAllQuery.java:904)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepare(ReadAllQuery.java:835)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:673)
        ... 151 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to de.drvbund.pub.enums.DokumentTypSchluessel
```

I guess the framework takes the `toString()`-representation of the `Enum` element from the query, assumes it is the entity attribute value, that needs to be converted to its corresponding dbValue and tries to call the `convertToDatabaseColumn()` method passing the `String`. I just don't know how to do this correctly.

How can I retrieve entities filtered by an `Enum` attribute value with JPA?

Comment: Have you tried passing in the value as a parameter - use the Enum type directly instead of a String as the error is looking for the DokumentTypSchluessel when forming the query but getting your string instead.

Comment: Yes I tried using the enum type directly by using a `CriteriaQuery` instead of a query String, but it lead to the same error.

Comment: How did you add it exactly? Your String above is JPQL, so you should be able to just use ```entityManager.createQuery("SELECT d FROM DokumentTyp d WHERE d.schluessel = ?1", DokumentTyp.class).setParameter(1, DokumentTypSchluessel.VORBEREITUNG).getSingleResult();``` without having to resort to criteria queries. If you tried using a parameter, I would expect the stack to be slightly different and may point to a slightly different issue or cause

Comment: Yes! With that it works! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by the suggestion of Chris:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT d FROM DokumentTyp d WHERE d.schluessel = ?1", DokumentTyp.class)
             .setParameter(1, DokumentTypSchluessel.VORBEREITUNG)
             .getSingleResult();
```